# Why can't I read the input string using this scanf function?

Tags: c++, scanf

Input: 3 Elephant

Output: Ele

but the input string is not read.. any help?

Thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int n;
    string input;

    while ( scanf ("%d %s",&n, input ) != EOF ) 
    {
        string sub = input.substr(0,n);
        cout<< sub;
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::string` and `scanf` are incompatibile. Use either `std::string` and `std::cin` or `scanf` and `char` buffers.

Comment: If you try this in a decent compiler it will error http://ideone.com/UymexB

Comment: use  `cin>>n>>input;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf` - is a C function. It knows nothing about C++ class `std::string`. Its format specifier `%s` is used to enter data in a character array.

You mixed two languages: C and C++. It is a bad style of programming. Instead of the loop

```
while ( scanf ("%d %s",&n, input ) != EOF ) 
{

        string sub = input.substr(0,n);
        cout<< sub;
}
```

use the following loop

```
while ( std::cin >> n >> input ) 
{

        string sub = input.substr(0,n);
        cout<< sub;
}
```